# How to handle Dojo keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, dojo, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I am using [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) and I want my Dojo application to work with keyboard shortcuts.

I have implemented Dojo keyboard shortcuts by using following snippet

```
var name="Factory"
var myTabContainer = dijit.byId("contentTab");
var tempid = "contentTab_tablist_" + name;
var tab = dijit.byId(tempid);

dojo.connect(tab, "onkeypress", function(e){
    switch(e.charOrCode){
        case 'h':
            alert('hi dojo h');
            return false;
        case  'j':
            alert('hi dojo j');
            return false;
        default :
            alert('default');
            return false;
    }
}
);
```

Using the above piece of code, Dojo shortcut works for very initial time only.

I mean that the shortcut will only work until no mouse key is pressed. but once mouse click is fired... then Dojo shortcut stops working.

Passing through huge bizarre

Comment: you have syntax errors, and you obviously haven't used a console to check the error messages you get.